# How you read PDF with python 3.x using only default libraries?

Tags: python, pdf, robotframework

I need to read information from PDF file using, python or robotframework, however I can not install any external libraries due to my company rules. Is it possible and how I could do that?

Comment: you might have to write your own pdf reader; documentation about pdf is here: https://www.iso.org/standard/51502.html. create your own module; Also if its real business case there are typically options to choose package - proove its necessary and get official security approval to include it.

Comment: probably I will, it takes too much to get approvals from admins and etc..

Comment: You have a harsh admin then. Writing a moderately successful PDF reader from scratch might take you about a year. The only thing you'll learn is that there is no such thing as a 100% perfect PDF reader (because there are lots of *really* badly created PDFs out there).

Comment: Given the nature of the question and the subsequent comments, I'd recommend you revise the question to one of a more technical programming related one or accept one of the below answers.

Comment: I don't get why comments say this is "opinion based" or that it needs rephrasing to be a technical question. IMO, this question is factual and technical. It is asking for standard python libraries for reading pdfs. I have the same question and am surprised if there are none.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is!

You'll just have to write the parser for PDFs from scratch. You can find the PDF 1.7 file specification [over here at Adobe.com](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), it's only 756 pages.

On a more serious note, not being able to use any external libraries in any circumstances is idiotic – that company rule is misguided, and those who enacted it probably are using oodles of unvetted external code anyway.

(If you are allowed to install system packages, though, `pdftotext` from Poppler might help you a bit.)

Comment: As I have spent most of my work life in such type of companies - "can not install" typically means you can but security procedures to get permission for package will take from 6 month up to 1+ year ... You may not have time to wait that much so it becomes easier to write your own parser

Answer (score -3):

I have used this one: https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/tools/pdf2txt.py.

Used the script to convert PDFs to strings and then tested the contents.

Comment: Why does this not count as an "external library"?

Comment: In no way, but still better than nothing.